# Can someone help me port the fat32 library used in the x16 to my homebrew 65c02?

Tags: hardware, 65c02

A little background:

As a retired electronics technician, (not engineer), I decided to design and build a 65C02 based computer. Only after building it did I realize how important advanced or experienced programming really was. I wrote enough code to boot and provide a simple command interpreter. I only have a basic knowledge of assembly using the vasm assembler. But it was enough to port the fat32 library written by George Foot to my computer and make it work. It gives a response to the 'dir' command much like MS_dos 6. It displays the directories first then the files. It displays the file name, ext, size, date, and time for each file. I can read and load files into memory. I patted myself on the back for getting that far with my limited programming skills only to realize the computer is useless without being able to create and delete files and directories. (His version only allows reading) Knowing even less about fat32 I tried to add the api's but even with the help of chat gpt I get wrapped around the axles and nothing has worked.  The computer is built as an isa card that plugs in to a passive 8 bit isa backplane that can use other isa cards. Its currently running at 10Mhz and uses ps2 keyboard and mouse, has sd card reader and rtc module,  512k banked ram, and a composite text monitor, all on the card. The rtc module doesn't work as I haven't written the I2C code for it yet.
[image: schematic]

[image: view]

[image: boot]

[image: directory command]

I've since found a complete [fat32 library](https://github.com/commanderx16/x16-rom/tree/master/dos/fat32) written by Frank van den Hoef and Michael Steil for the x16 project. It's billed as usable in any 65C02 system using about 8k of rom, 1.5k of ram, and only a few bytes of zero page memory. However, it's written using the ca65 assembler which I have but am not familiar with. Nor am I familiar with writing configuration files for the assembler.

I guess what i'm looking for is someone willing to take an old retired guy, with limited programming skills, by the hand and help port a complicated piece of software to a computer that is not commercial, has no monitary value, just a homebrew hobby commputer, just for fun.

Any takers?

Comment: While neat project, the only retro part is the CPU. All the FAT32 code and compilers and assemblers are modern, so this is about porting modern code to modern compilers to a modern platform using an old CPU, is that right?

Comment: Yes, and if you noticed, it has no graphics yet, just a text monitor. I planned to have an isa graphics card eventually. probably simalar to the vera in the x16. Again, not retro.

Comment: Nice Job. Like it. Maybe except for my dislike of I2C. Have you thought about using a PC104 layout instead? In any case, above does seem neither like a question, nor on-topic for RC.SE, as all components involved are of new development with no relation to any historic machine - same way as a X16 would be of-topic here. Not sure if Meta.RC.SE would be of any help.

Comment: Can anyone suggest a compatable forum for this topic?

Comment: 6502.org, THE 6502 forums.

Comment: Excellent project!

Comment: This is off-topic, although not because it’s insufficiently retro, but because it is too open-ended: it does not ask about a single specific problem, and is more of an invitation to join a project than a question.

Answer (score 7):

Arguably, it would be easier to port your code to ca65 than the fat32 code from ca65. The ca65 toolset is quite robust. 90+% of that code (at a glance at least) is "just 6502". I don't see any involved macros or anything. Most of the assembler commands and such are instructions to the linker (.global, .import, etc.) on how to deal with undefined labels. That's where ca65 stands up from simpler assemblers.

Reading FAT32 is probably an order of magnitude easier than writing it, as you likely discovered.

I haven't looked at the fat32 code in detail, hopefully they isolated how sectors are read and written (that would be the part that's truly specific to your system, the rest is generic).

Porting to ca65 should be straightforward, it may not be trivial, but should be straightforward and mostly mechanical. There's only a few concepts you need to wrap your head around about what ca65 and it's linker are doing, then your code will probably move right over.

And do head over to the 6502.org forums, they're a helpful bunch and know their stuff.

Comment: True, while CA65 doesn't really stand up to mainframe assembler, it is generations ahead of many other micro assemblers when it comes to configuration management. Would go the same way.